# How could I dynamically change dropdown select content

Tags: javascript, jquery

Like an airline website.

When you select the departure airport.

the content of arrival airport will be changed correspondinly.

For examle, if you choose Paris at departure airport. Then, Paris should not appear in the arrival airport.

How could I do this, any keyword or term to search for further information ?

Thanks

Comment: Just filter an array according to the selected value from select one and update select two from it.

Answer (score 2):

Check working demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jy9kfhmd/2/)

Use jQuery selector to find the destination options element, iterate to hide the one targeted:

```
function changeDestination(target) {
    var options = $('#destination option');
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        var opt = $(options[i]);
        opt.show();

        if (opt.attr('name') === target.value) {
            opt.hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Joy, thanks for your help, but how could I modify your code to apply to my work, http://52.68.64.234:3457/ , i could change the destination value, because the DOM structure is diffrent from yours. any idea ?

Comment: I think you need to learn the idea and apply to your application by yourself. So that you can learn most.

Comment: thanks, but i got your idea, but the generated options are `li a` DOMs and hard to see the regularity on my case to hide the target value :(

Comment: Well. Maybe you can edit the question to show the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you dynamically add an Option to a select....

```
var x = document.getElementById("selectid");
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.text = "newOption";
x.add(option);
```

There is also a remove() method you can employ.

I think a combination of those will get done what you need to get done.  Google "add option to select javascript" and "remove option from select javascript" and i think you will be on your way.